# cmd to powershell transition in batch-script

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch

Is there a way of writing a batch-script that's executed via `C:\>cmd.exe a.bat` to switch into `powershell.exe` and run the remaining lines of code?

```
1. | echo "Hi. I'm cmd.exe."
2. | powershell
3. | echo "Now, I'm PowerShell.exe! Look:"
4. | get-random
```

This just **stops** after line #2 waiting for input.

Comment: See this StackOverflow question: [How to execute powershell commands from a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037146/how-to-execute-powershell-commands-from-a-batch-file)

Comment: So, looks like one just simply puts: `powershell -Command "& {echo "Now, I''m PowerShell.exe! Look:";get-random}"` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a .bat file and use this for the first line:

```
;@Findstr -bv ;@F "%~f0" | powershell -noprofile -command - & goto:eof
```

This line pipes all lines from the current file ("%~f0") that don't start with ";@F" to PowerShell to be executed. The remaining lines would be PowerShell code. Here is an example.

```
;@Findstr -bv ;@F "%~f0" | powershell -noprofile -command - & goto:eof

$procCount = (Get-Process).Count
Write-Host "There are $procCount processes running right now." -fore green
Start-Sleep 5
```